# Actionscript access global / class variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is my code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class MyClass extends Sprite
{
    private var abc:String = "123";
    public function MyClass()
    {

    }

    public function myfunc():void
    {
        dispatch("456");
    }

    private function dispatch(abc:String):void
    {
        trace(abc);
    }
}
}
```

When call the `myfunc()` function the trace will return `456`. How can I get it to access to the global variable?

Thank you.

Comment: first of all why are you using the same name for argument variable and global variable?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`this` keyword](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#this):

```
private function dispatch(abc:String):void
    {
       trace( this.abc );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `private var abc:String = "123";` is not global variable. It's a private member variable of the class. It's scope is the full class. When you add parameter in a member method  with the same name, that parameter has the local scope in that method and that local parameter variable hides the class member of the same name.

```
private function dispatch(abc:String):void {
    // here abc has local scope and it hides the class member abc
}
```

You have two options to solve this:

1. Simply use a different name for the parameter. For example, `private function dispatch(ab:String):void`. Now `ab` is local variable, `abc` is class member variable.
2. If you must use the same name for parameter then use `this.abc` to access the class member.